# Adding Facebook log in button - can't retrieve email address on server side

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook

I am trying to add a simple log in with Facebook button to my ASP.NET (C#) website. All I need is on the server side to retrieve the Facebook user's email address once they have logged in.

I was trying to use [this example](http://area72.ro/general-it/how-to-login-via-facebook-in-asp-net.html) but it seems that the cookie "fbs_appid" is no longer used and instead there is one called "fbsr_appid".

How can I change the sample to use the different cookie? Alternately does anyone have a working example of retrieving the logged in Facebook user's email address.

I know there is an SDK I can use but I want to keep things simple. The above example would be perfect if it worked.

Comment: I tried to use the C# SDK but the documentation is incomplete and the sample in [getting started](http://csharpsdk.org/docs/web/getting-started) doesn't work (FacebookClient is not recognised). Does anyone have any working code for the SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get the information needed using the fbsr cookie. I created the following class which does all of the work to confirm the user logged in with Facebook and then retrieves the user's details:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Configuration;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

namespace HarlequinShared
{
public class FacebookLogin
{
    protected static string _appId = null;
    protected static string AppId
    {
        get
        {
            if (_appId == null)
                _appId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FacebookAppId"] ?? null;
            return _appId;
        }
    }

    protected static string _appSecret = null;
    protected static string AppSecret
    {
        get
        {
            if (_appSecret == null)
                _appSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FacebookAppSecret"] ?? null;
            return _appSecret;
        }
    }

    public static FacebookUser CheckLogin()
    {
        string fbsr = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["fbsr_" + AppId].Value;

        int separator = fbsr.IndexOf(".");
        if (separator == -1)
        {
            return null;
        }

        string encodedSig = fbsr.Substring(0, separator);
        string payload = fbsr.Substring(separator + 1);

        string sig = Base64Decode(encodedSig);

        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        Dictionary<string, string> data = serializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>>(Base64Decode(payload));

        if (data["algorithm"].ToUpper() != "HMAC-SHA256")
        {
            return null;
        }

        HMACSHA256 crypt = new HMACSHA256(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(AppSecret));
        crypt.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(payload));
        string expectedSig = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(crypt.Hash);

        if (sig != expectedSig)
        {
            return null;
        }

        string accessTokenResponse = FileGetContents("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=" + AppId + "&redirect_uri=&client_secret=" + AppSecret + "&code=" + data["code"]);
        NameValueCollection options = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(accessTokenResponse);

        string userResponse = FileGetContents("https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=" + options["access_token"]);

        userResponse = Regex.Replace(userResponse, @"\\u([\dA-Fa-f]{4})", v => ((char)Convert.ToInt32(v.Groups[1].Value, 16)).ToString());

        FacebookUser user = new FacebookUser();

        Regex getValues = new Regex("(?<=\"email\":\")(.+?)(?=\")");
        Match infoMatch = getValues.Match(userResponse);
        user.Email = infoMatch.Value;

        getValues = new Regex("(?<=\"first_name\":\")(.+?)(?=\")");
        infoMatch = getValues.Match(userResponse);
        user.FirstName = infoMatch.Value;

        getValues = new Regex("(?<=\"last_name\":\")(.+?)(?=\")");
        infoMatch = getValues.Match(userResponse);
        user.LastName = infoMatch.Value;

        return user;
    }

    protected static string FileGetContents(string url)
    {
        string result;
        WebResponse response;
        WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
        response = request.GetResponse();
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            result = sr.ReadToEnd();
            sr.Close();
        }
        return result;
    }

    protected static string Base64Decode(string input)
    {
        UTF8Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
        string encoded = input.Replace("=", string.Empty).Replace('-', '+').Replace('_', '/');
        var decoded = Convert.FromBase64String(encoded.PadRight(encoded.Length + (4 - encoded.Length % 4) % 4, '='));
        var result = encoding.GetString(decoded);
        return result;
    }

}

public class FacebookUser
{
    public string UID { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
}
```

And then I can use this in my login page:

```
FacebookUser user = FacebookLogin.CheckLogin();
if (user != null)
{
Response.Write("&lt;p&gt;" + user.Email);
Response.Write("&lt;p&gt;" + user.FirstName);
Response.Write("&lt;p&gt;" + user.LastName);
}
```

This is further explained [here](http://blog.johnavis.com/blog/default.asp?id=605).

I believe that this method is secure and does the job as simply as possible. Please comment if there is any concerns.

Answer (score 0):

This is not at all how you should be doing things, especially if you are trying to do it on the server side. You should not use the cookie.
The different sdks make things simpler, they (especially the official ones) stay up to date with facebook changes, unlike the example you provided that just stopped working when the cookie name was changed.

I'm not a C# developer, and never tried to use facebook from that environment so I can't tell you exactly how to do it with C#, but this is the main concept:

When you send the user for authentication (assumed [Server Side](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/server-side/) Flow) you need to ask the user for permissions for anything but basic and public user information.
The email field is filed under "extended permission" and you need to ask for it specifically, something like this:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_url=YOUR_REDIRECT_URI&scope=email
```

(You can read more about permissions [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/))

Once the user authorized your app and granted you with the permissions, you can then ask for that data.
You can do it in the server side by asking for the ["/me"](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me) graph path (or just the email: ["me?fields=email"](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me?fields=email)).

You can also do it in the client side with the [javascript sdk](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/):

```
FB.api("/me", function(response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

Comment: I wanted the user to be able to login in a popup rather than by redirection.

Comment: So use the [Client-Side Authentication](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/client-side/). The getting of the user data (and the email field) after the authentication should work the same. One thing though, tokens generated for server side auth "live" longer (valid for a month i think), unlike the client side generated tokens.